# Difference between "adiós" and "chau"?

Tags: diferencias-entre-palabras, saludos

What is the difference between *adiós* and *chau*?

Do they both mean "goodbye"?

Examples:

- I am going now, see you tomorrow, ¡adiós!
- I am going now, see you tomorrow, ¡chau!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Traditionally, *adiós* is used for someone leaving for an extended period of time or with no expectation of seeing them again.

*Chau* is informal, and would virtually always imply you'd be expecting to see them again relatively soon.

If you're leaving work and going to meet up with coworkers later for drinks, *chau* is better than *adiós*. If you're going abroad and won't see your parents for a year or two, *adiós* is better. If you go to a store and the worker there didn't expect to see you ever again, they'll probably use *adiós*, but if it's a corner store and they know, you're more likely to hear *chau*.

Modern usage may vary some, and different countries may treat them slightly differently (and certainly there dozens more with similar but not exactly the same connotations), but the distinction ought to hold up pretty panhispanicly.

Comment: Muchas gracias Guifa!

Comment: I don't think you will hear *chau* outside Argentina and maybe Uruguay. You can hear *chao* elsewhere, but it is not so usual. In Spain, for instance, we would use *hasta luego* with this meaning.

Comment: You definitely hear "chau" in Chile and Peru.  I'm pretty sure it will be recognized in Colombia, Mexico, and Puerto Rico.

Comment: Both forms `chau` and `chao` are acepted words but barbarisms as they come from modern as recent addendum. People may and will understand them and I know maaaany people that use them but they´re fancy weird for writing and should not be used. Mostly girls or youngsters use them.

Comment: @eduyayo obviously ignores that _chau_ is being used in Argentina for at least 100 years

Comment: It is still far too new. Also in argentina thet say (and write) "podés" instead of "puedes" but... Does not matter the correctness or the like... Maybe... You judge

Comment: @eduyayo They don't use *podés* instead of *puedes*, they simply use *vos* instead of *tú*.  There is absolutely nothing incorrect about it.  There are plenty of words that have been imported across the Spanish speaking world that I find absolutely hideous sounding, but *chao* has been so well integrated that, apart from its informality, I can't imagine why anyone has a problem with it except for using it in formal contexts.

Comment: This is just my own guess, but maybe we in Argentina we stopped using Adios or Ve con Dios many decades ago because it supposedly contradicts the 2nd catholic commandment. Of course nowadays we don't use it because it sounds.. weird to us, like, way too foreign. Same with the puedes/podés example above

Comment: @guifa Haha... so you don´t even know that using `vos` instead of `tú` you should say `podéis`: `vos podéis` is the correct Spanish. Please, just do not disturb. Please, read more. Please, learn Spanish before you come to mislead this people...

Comment: @eduyayo read what I said carefully. In Argentina, they do not replace *puedes* with *podés*. They replace *tú* with *vos*. *Vos*, in turn, has a different conjugation paradigm, thus obligating the use *podés*. When answering the question *¿Cómo estás?* with *Estoy bien*, one isn't relaxing estás with estoy, rather tú with yo. That estoy changes to estás is quite secondary to the main change — a different subject.

Comment: hence... when sayin: `¿Cómo estáis vos?` you should say `estáis` and not `estás`. And same goes for whatever the thing: `vos coméis` and not `vos comés`. `vos podéis` and not `vos podés`. That´s part of the accent and not part of the correction. Same thing happens in my place where we use `ye` instead of `es`... It does not make it right.

Comment: @eduyayo te confundes el vos reverencial con el vos informal, que tienen paradigmas de conjugación diferentes (y de todas formas, como rechazas evoluciones lingüísticas, debe reconocer la forma verdaderamente correcta: *vos estades*). Como asturfalante, te puedo asegurar que la situación de *ye* es muy diferente. *Ye* es la correcta conjugación de *ser* en asturiano. Usar *ye* en castellano es hablar en amestáu, el cual ni es propiamente castellano ni asturiano. Recomiéndote aprender un poco de la historia de la lengua, o bien leer las secciones relevantes de la *Gramática* de la RAE.

Comment: @eduyayo and guifa. This is not the place to have debates. And remember to follow basic civil etiquette when discussing a subject in which you don't agree, independent of who is right and who is wrong. The place to have such debate is the chat. Thank you both and continue the good work!

Comment: @eduyayo consider this a warning. In general in SL&U and probably most of the hispanic world, we adhere to the rules and regulations of language decided by the Royal Spanish Academy of language that groups and discusses language with all academies of all hispanic countries. Your opinion is irrelevant in this matter, specially if it is formulated in a disrespectful manner.

Comment: All writings from the RAE note it as a dialect. If mine opinion is irrelevant in this matter yours also, specially if it is supporting one formulated in a disrespectfull manner. Notice that the `requeté` deleted his comment.

Comment: @eduyayo The fact that it is a dialect isn't a value judgement. Being a dialect is not "correct" or "incorrect" it is what it is, a dialect. And in this case a dialect that is **recognized** by the RAE, which means that is **recognized** as belonging to the Spanish language as a whole. Your previous statements besides their correctness or non-correctness make ad-hominem attacks on the other participants of the site and that behavior is **unacceptable** and will **not** be tolerated. You have been *warned*. This is not a threat, but a *warning*.

Answer (score 1):

They mean the same. *Chao* (or *chau*) is a bit more informal. It comes from the Italian *ciao*, which also means "goodbye" (in Italian).

Comment: In italian, ciao also means hello if I'm not mistaken. ;)

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. It does, indeed; but in Spanish, we only use it meaning "good bye".